# Ionic Cordova project not working for Huawei because HSM not found

Tags: cordova, huawei-mobile-services

I have a simple mobile app builded with Ionic and Cordova and I tried to publish to App Gallery and they said:
 `Your App has been approved. ­Notes: Since your App has not been integrated with HMS yet, It cannot be used or displayed on the HMS. If integration of HMS is needed, please refer to: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Library/android-sdk-download-0000001064112371`

For the current project I use firebasex notifications plugin.

How should I proceed?

- install hsm-push?
- remove firebasex for huawei builds?
- what about the code inside controllers? should I check if is a huawei phone and apply some sort of settings/methods-call?
- what about the plugin declaration in app.module?
- what about the HSM Core SDK? - https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Library/android-sdk-download-0000001064112371

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your app has Google libs and doesn't have Huawei libs and it's published in AppGallery in state, that allows to install app only for users with google services.

Whenever the application that you upload on AppGallery is not showing up on a phone that does not have GMS (such as P40) will not be shown in AppGallery, but if in example you have P30, it will be shown on AppGallery,  In order to have your app VISIBLE to non-GMS phones (P40 and above) you have to use HMS converter by Huawei, where all GMS dependencies are turned to HMS dependencies.

Basically HMS toolkit, you can check the video guide: https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/training/course/video/C101638944154324019

You may also use  official Huawei Cordova Push plugin for notifications:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hmscore/cordova-plugin-hms-push
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hmscore/ionic-native-hms-push